# Filling list according to rules

Tags: python, list

Sorry for the not-so-explicit title, my problem is very specific and I have no idea how to make it short.

Here's the thing: I have a list of exactly 8 elements that are -1, 0 or +1. I want to change the 0s in either -1 or +1. The thing is that sometime I can't know how to fill it; I just know that at the end, I must have no 0; exactly 5 times -1 and 3 times +1. The idea would be, that given a list containing some 0s, I end up with all the admissible lists (with good number of -1/+1) I can obtain by changing the values of the 0s.
For instance, imagine the list is:

```
L  = [-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1,-1]
```

As L contains 4 times -1 and 2 times +1, I would like to explore what would happen with:

```
L1 = [-1,-1,-1, 1,-1, 1, 1,-1] 
L2 = [-1,-1,-1,-1, 1, 1, 1,-1]
```

I had an idea which is to do as follows: count how much 0 there are, count to two power that, convert it in binary, and fill accordingly; putting -1 instead of 0, and discarding the cases that have not the good ration of +1/-1. That seems kind of overkill to me, and I'm pretty sure there is a smarter way to do it.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Please specify exactly what you expect from this algorithm. Do you want all possible lists where the zeros are replaced by -1 or 1 to fulfil the 5/3 split, or do you want only one combination out of all possible combinations?

Comment: Or, do you want all possible combinations of five `-1` and three `1`, in which case the original list becomes irrelevant.

Comment: As you said: I need all possible list where zeros are replaced by +1 or -1 to have the good split. The initial list is there because i filled it using some other rules I did not mentioned to keep it simple; the calculation of the problem using the all 3 choose 8 combination would be way too long (i guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the easiest way I don't know, but it is a way to get all possible lists:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import permutations

L  = [-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1,-1]
counter = Counter(L)
perm_list = [1]*(3-counter[1]) + [-1]*(5-counter[-1])

# get all permutations of the numbers you want to add
p = [list(p) for p in permutations(perm_list)]

# remove duplicates
new_p = []
for elem in p:
    if elem not in new_p:
        new_p.append(elem)
p = new_p

# insert all permutations in the list instead of zeros
out_lists=[]
for x in range(len(p)):
    out_lists.append([i if i!=0 else p[x].pop() for i in L])
out_lists
```

You can then access the individual lists with out_lists[i].

output:

```
[[-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1]]
```

Comment: It looks like what I was expecting. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here a direct approach, no use of external libraries or such.

```
L = [-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1,-1]

index_zeros = [i for i, j in enumerate(L) if j == 0]
index_ones = [i for i, j in enumerate(L) if j == 1]
index_neg_ones = []

n_ones = len(index_ones)
if n_ones < 3:
    index_ones += index_zeros[:3 - n_ones]
    index_zeros = index_zeros[3 - n_ones:]

n_zeros = len(index_zeros)
n_neg_ones = len(L) - n_zeros - len(index_ones)
if n_neg_ones < 5:
    index_neg_ones += index_zeros[:5 - n_neg_ones]
    index_zeros = index_zeros[5 - n_neg_ones:]

index_neg_ones = [i for i in range(len(L)) if i not in index_zeros+index_ones]


for i in index_ones:
    L[i] = 1
for i in index_neg_ones:
    L[i] = -1

print(L)
```

Output

```
[-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1]
```

Other tests

```
L = [0,-1,0, 0, 0, 1, -1,-1]
[1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1]

L = [0,0,0, 0, 0, 1, -1,0]
[1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1]
```

Note: I think the most elegant way is to that by recursion... and don't forget the trivial solution `[1]*3 + [-1]*5`!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like there's no guarantee that this code will end up with five `-1` and three  `1`

Comment: @ Pranav Hosangad yes, right, I will update it. I was confused concerning the rule for the substitution

Answer (score 0):

You can first count how many positive and negatives ones you will need. Then, create the `filler` list containing the right number of positive and negative ones to fill the remaining zeros. By shuffling the `filler` list, you can ensure that your output is uniformly distributed among all lists meeting your count requirement:

```
from collections import Counter
from random import shuffle

L  = [-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1,-1]

ctr = Counter(L)

need_neg_ones = 5 - ctr[-1]
need_pos_ones = 3 - ctr[1]

filler = [-1] * need_neg_ones + [1] * need_pos_ones
shuffle(filler)
filler = iter(filler)

res = [x if x != 0 else next(filler) for x in L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print all combinations:

```
import itertools

L  = [0,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1,-1] # input data example

m1 = 5 - L.count(-1)   # count of -1's needed
p1 = 3 - L.count(1)    # count of +1's needed
zi = [i for i, x in enumerate(L) if x == 0] # indices of all zeroes

if m1 >= 0 and p1 >= 0 and m1+p1 == len(zi):
    # in L2: fill 0 -> +1 everywhere, -1's will be handled below
    L2 = [1 if x == 0 else x for x in L]
    for m1fill in itertools.combinations(zi, m1):
        L3 = L2.copy()
        for i in m1fill:
            L3[i] = -1
        print(L3)
else:
    print("not valid or not possible")
```